# Doctrine 2 : Best way to manage many-to-many associations

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

**Doctrine2 ORM have 2 technical ways to handle many-to-many associations :**

1/ For a "simple" relation between 2 entities, and without additionnal attribute :

- Use **@ManyToMany associations between entities**
- In this case, the link table is used directly, without an association entity

2/ When link table introduces extra fields or more than 2 entities :

- Use **an association class**, ie an "real" entity to map the link table
- In this case, the direct ManyToMany association is replaced by **OneToMany/ManyToOne** associations between the participating entities

These 2 implementations are quite different.

But, in some cases, **future business requirements can quickly need to change simple associations, by adding extra fields for example.**
In this case, we must replace direct ManyToMany associations in existing entities by the second implementation and refactor affected code.

- So, is it a good way to always use association entities to handle all
  ManyToMany associations ?
- Otherwise, what are the best practices for
  choosing the good implementation and handle these kind of domain
  model evolutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a good reason to belief that in the near future you will have extra properties on your ManyToMany join table then it's a good idea to make an entity out of precaution. If not then it's better to use the normal ManyToMany relationship. Then when a change is needed you can update your schema along with your code. If you try to follow the Single responsibility principle then you can avoid refactoring large amounts of code.